# Having an Watchman Issue React native

Tags: react-native, npm, npm-start

```
To reload the app press "r"
To open developer menu press "d"

jest-haste-map: Watchman crawl failed. Retrying once with node crawler.
  Usually this happens when watchman isn't running. Create an empty `.watchmanconfig` file in your project's root folder or initialize a git or hg repository in your project.
  Error: Watchman error: std::__1::system_error: open: /Users/abdullahshahid/Documents/caremiles-react-native-repo: Operation not permitted. Make sure watchman is running for this project. See https://facebook.github.io/watchman/docs/troubleshooting.
/Users/abdullahshahid/Documents/caremiles-react-native-repo/node_modules/metro-hermes-compiler/src/emhermesc.js:77
          throw ex;
          ^

Error: std::__1::system_error: open: /Users/abdullahshahid/Documents/caremiles-react-native-repo: Operation not permitted
    at BunserBuf.<anonymous> (/Users/abdullahshahid/Documents/caremiles-react-native-repo/node_modules/fb-watchman/index.js:95:23)
    at BunserBuf.emit (node:events:527:28)
    at BunserBuf.process (/Users/abdullahshahid/Documents/caremiles-react-native-repo/node_modules/bser/index.js:292:10)
    at /Users/abdullahshahid/Documents/caremiles-react-native-repo/node_modules/bser/index.js:247:12
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:77:11)
Emitted 'error' event on WatchmanWatcher instance at:
    at Client.<anonymous> (/Users/abdullahshahid/Documents/caremiles-react-native-repo/node_modules/jest-haste-map/build/lib/WatchmanWatcher.js:172:10)
    at Client.emit (node:events:527:28)
    at BunserBuf.<anonymous> (/Users/abdullahshahid/Documents/caremiles-react-native-repo/node_modules/fb-watchman/index.js:107:12)
    at BunserBuf.emit (node:events:527:28)
    at /Users/abdullahshahid/Documents/caremiles-react-native-repo/node_modules/bser/index.js:249:12
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:77:11) {
  watchmanResponse: {
    error: 'std::__1::system_error: open: /Users/abdullahshahid/Documents/caremiles-react-native-repo: Operation not permitted',
    version: '2022.05.30.00'
  }
}

Node.js v18.2.0
```

I give permission to watchman and terminal in System Preferences > Security and Privacy Full Disk And also tried watch-del-all command and watchman shutdown-server command but still no success

I have mac os monetery need help ?

Comment: Having the same issue on same OS, did you end up finding a solution that wasn't uninstalling watchman?

Comment: Having the same issue on same OS

Answer (score 12):

run `brew uninstall watchman` in your terminal should solve it

Answer (score 1):

For macos Monterey you will need to uninstall watchman.

run **brew uninstall watchman** in your terminal

Comment: then how can we work with watchman when its needed?

Answer (score 0):

I had my repo in my Documents folder on my M1 macbook pro. [This thread](https://github.com/facebook/watchman/issues/977) said to move it out of that folder and now it runs great!

Answer (score 0):

One of the answers here mentioned placing the repo under Documents, but that did not work for me. Instead, I placed it under the Users/myuser/ directory and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing posted here helped me. Instead, I tried this and solved the issue successfully.

**Solution:**

```
echo 999999 | sudo tee -a /proc/sys/fs/inotify/max_user_watches
```

run this cmd in the terminal and thank me later!